# The client API want me to reply back with a xml

Tags: php, api

I am working on an API in php. The client API sent the results to my url as an xml file. I use `file_get_contents` to read the xml file they want me to reply back `<xml>Accepted</xml>`. How to do this?

Example:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{
    //Read the xmlinput and write to the file

    $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
    // ..Do something..

    return('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml>Accepted</xml>');
}
```

I am not sure how to send back xml to same session without initiating new curl.

Can we use CGI? If so, how?

Comment: Generally, you just echo it (?) - They will read the response to their request, and you create the response by 'outputting stuff'.

Comment: Ofc, you don't manually generate xml like that, but as a test, it's fine.

Comment: [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) alone won't output anything. You need to call `echo`.

Comment: I know return does not work in this case.But asking what to do to send xml

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SoapClient? if so is it compliant with the version 1.2?

```
<?php
// ...
$client = new SoapClient('some.wsdl', ['soap_version' => SOAP_1_2]);
```

You can output this (RFC7303 superseded RFC3023).

```
<?php
// ...
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
```